# Can an IIS website on any port be the target of a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, subdomain

I have an IIS webserver hosting lets say www.mysite.com on port 80. I have several other websites on ports 8881-8889. I would like to have sub domains so sd1.mysite.com resolves to the site on port 8881, s2.mysite.com on port 8883, etc.

This is on a Windows 2008 Server with DNS roles. I added an AAAA Host to the domain, and proper bindings in IIS.

At this point I can get sd1.mysite.com:8881 to resolve, but not  sd1.mysite.com (404).

Is there anyway to ttell what I am doing wrong with the information provided?

[image]

[image: dns 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Calling A and AAAA records subdomains is technically correct but is not how people generally refer to them. They just call them host records, A records or AAAA records. Most people generally think of subdomains as child domains of a parent domain (that's how I generally think of them).
2. An AAAA record is an IPv6 address record. You probably want to create and use an A record, which is an IPv4 address record.
3. You cannot use DNS to specify the port for a DNS record, except in the case of SRV DNS records, which web browsers don't support or use.
4. If you want to host multiple web sites on the server without having to specify the port number when accessing them then you should be using host headers. The other alternative would be to use a different ip address for each web site.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to use a different port than standard port 80? You can use host headers and have multiple sub domains point to different sites with different host headers.

If you have a wild card SSL, you can use appcmd command to use a single up address to host multiple sites with port 443.